# Does Ubuntu erase all the Windows partitions with the Erase Disk option?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

I'm finally getting rid of  Windows 10 and fresh installing Ubuntu for the first time. Pre-installed Windows 10 comes with some [hidden partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjdle.png) The last 3 NTFS partitions are the ones [I have access on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1jBh.png).

So, technically my harddrive size is 931 GB, but I can only use 916 GB of it.

What I want to know is that when I do "erase disk and install Ubuntu"

[image: installer dialog]

will it wipe out everything on 931 GB harddrive (including those protected system and recovery partitions)? If yes, then does it mean that Ubuntu will let me use all the 931 GB storage (unlike Windows)? If no, then how can I get rid of those protected partitions before installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes 'erase and install' will cause all partitions on the disk to be erased & system installed. I can't make out the release in your picture (Ubuntu currently has four installers depending on ISO chosen), but it looks like `ubiquity` and a desktop install.

Comment: @karel It kind of does, but not excatly. That post is specifically about boot screen only and it is also kind of outdated.

Comment: use the something else option and you can decide yourself what to remove ;)